# Pairwise edge-disjoint path on tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let T be a tree with 2k leaves. Prove that there exists k pairwise
edge-disjoint paths in T connecting the leaves in pairs.

My attempt:
 Assume by contrary, let $p_i$ and $p_j$ be paths having an edge in common for $i\neq j$. Then the paths are overlapping as they determine 4 distinct leaves. Hence we proved the statement. Am I correct guys or I need to modify my arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your argument at all.  What is the range of $i$ and $j$?  Why are you talking about paths with a common edge when the statement is about edge-disjoint paths?  Then in the last sentence you say you proved the paths are overlapping, but didn't you assume that to begin with?

Comment: $i,j\in k$. I think the opposite of edge-disjoint path is a path with a common edge? Is that not?

Comment: Yes, that's the opposite, but it you're trying to prove the statement by contradiction, you have to assume that there do not exist $k$ edge-disjoint paths, not something about paths with a common edge.  I suggest trying to prove the statement by induction on the number of leaves.

Comment: @saulspatz, thank you for your correction.  Induction is not clear for me on basis

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by induction on $k$. I outline the proof leaving a couple of steps for you to do.

If $k=0$, the tree has no leaves, so it is the empty tree, and there are obviously no path joining any leaves.

Assume that the theorem is true of a tree with $2k$ leaves, and that we are given a tree with $2(k+1)$ leaves.  Recall that the depth of a node is the length of the shortest path from the node to a leaf, so that a leaf has depth $0$, the parent of a leaf has depth $1$ and so on.  There must be a node with more than one child. (Prove this!)  Choose a such a node $v$ of minimum depth.  If we eliminate two of the paths from $v$ down to the leaves, say to $l_1$ and $l_2$, we are left with a tree with $2k$ leaves, which can be partitioned into $k$ edge-disjoint paths joining leaves, by the induction hypothesis.  These paths are all edge disjoint from the path joining $l_1$ and $l_2$. (Prove!) This gives $k+1$ edge-disjoint paths in all, proving the theorem.

If you don't like the idea of an empty tree, you can start with a tree with two leaves for the basis.  This is proved just like the general case, starting with a node of minimum depth with two children.